# cursor iterate over null row

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, loops

I have a problem with my cursor and my database, if I do a while with !cursor.isAfterLast(), I have as much null result after the actual not null row as many times I launched the app (and put a value in the row)

This is my code :

```
public class DatabaseCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION = "drawinguess_local_database.db";

    // Table Names
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "image_bmp";

    // column names
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "image_title";
    private static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "image_author";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_data";

    // Table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "("+ COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME + "  TEXT," + KEY_AUTHOR + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";

    public DatabaseCreator(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);

        // create new table
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addEntry(String title, String author, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,    title);
        cv.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
        database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
    }

    public void addEntry(String title, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME,    title);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
        database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
    }

    public void addEntry(byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
        database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
    }

    public void updateLastTitle(String title) throws SQLiteException{
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String strSQL;

        //Cursor cursor = database.query(DATABASE_NAME, new String[]{"ID"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT "+ COLUMN_ID +" FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
        cursor.moveToLast();

        strSQL = "UPDATE " + DB_TABLE + " SET "+ KEY_NAME + " = \"" + title +"\" WHERE "+ COLUMN_ID +" = "+ cursor.getColumnCount();

        database.execSQL(strSQL);
    }

    public List<TitledBitmap> getAllTitledBitmap() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<TitledBitmap> titledBitmaps = new ArrayList<TitledBitmap>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{"image_title", "image_data"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            System.out.println("This is the title : " + cursor.getString(0));
            TitledBitmap titledBitmap = cursorToTitledBitmap(cursor);
            titledBitmaps.add(titledBitmap);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return titledBitmaps;
    }

    private TitledBitmap cursorToTitledBitmap(Cursor cursor) {
        TitledBitmap titledBitmap = new TitledBitmap();
        titledBitmap.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
        titledBitmap.setByteArray(cursor.getBlob(1));
        return titledBitmap;
    }

}
```

The problem is in getAllTitledBitmap(), I guess, thanks to the output of the Syso :

```
I/System.out: This is the title : TheValueThatWorked
          This is the title : null
          This is the title : null
```

Thank you in advance
Have a good day

Comment: Odds on the title(s) is/are null in the database, I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to search why but I don't know, otherwise, I use multiple activity to write data into the database, but I got only the last entry working, all the other are null
I use DatabaseCreator db = new DatabaseCreator(this) in all my activities, maybe this mess it up ?

Comment: Re comment *"I use DatabaseCreator db = new DatabaseCreator(this) in all my activities, maybe this mess it up ?"*. No that won't mess things up, that's how you should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue would be that you are using the byte[] only signature when using `addEntry` and this doesn't set the Title so it will be null.

Testing your code using :-

```
private void SO50301166() {
    DatabaseCreator dc = new DatabaseCreator(this);
    dc.addEntry("001 Added with author","Fred",new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0});
    dc.addEntry("002 Added",new byte[]{12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10});
    dc.addEntry(new byte[]{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30});
    dc.getAllTitledBitmap();
}
```

results in :-

```
05-11 23:10:28.306 1283-1283/? I/System.out: This is the title : 001 Added with author
    This is the title : 002 Added
    This is the title : null
```

i.e. using `dc.addEntry(new byte[]{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30});` doesn't set the title, thus it will be null.

So you probably want to change :-

```
public void addEntry(byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
    database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
}
```

To be :-

```
public void addEntry(byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,"No Title Provided"); //<<<< ADDED
    database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
}
```

However you could simplify your code and also not get the same issue with the **Author** by using :-

```
public void addEntry(String title, String author, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, title);
    cv.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    database.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public void addEntry(String title, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    addEntry(title,"No Author Proivided", image);
}

public void addEntry(byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    addEntry("No Title Provided",image);
}
```

i.e the main code is in the fullest signature the lesser signature call the next fuller signature.

using this would result in (using the previous test case) :-

```
This is the title : 001 Added with author
This is the title : 002 Added
This is the title : No Title Provided
```

Comment: Okay I see what you mean ! Thanks you are helpful, I will try this